# .zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context Terminal not working Macos Big Sur after changing Path

Tags: terminal, homebrew, macos-big-sur

after installing brew I added to the path with the following command:

> echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc

Now brew command is being recognized but not other one. For instance if I try to run ls it says command not found.

The message I receive when opening the terminal is

[image]

So I can not use the terminal.

I tried restarting, closing the terminal, using ITerm, but still can't anything..any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did is to use an alternative shell (https://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/) with that I could interact with terminal again, and from there modified the

> .zprofile

file. That brought terminal back to life.